# How can i use embedded ruby to take input from bootstrap form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to take input from a Bootstrap form and don't know how to use erb to take this input and save it to my column category, here category is as a foreign key in Product Model.

my product.rb

```
belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_one_attached :image
  validates :productname,  presence: true
  validates :productprice, presence:true


  validates :user_id, presence: true
```

```html
  <div class="form-group">
        <div class=" control-label col-sm-12">
      <label class="label1" ,for="sel1">Select category:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
       <option>Furniture</option>
       <option>Animals</option>
       <option>Electronics</option>
       <option>Computers</option>
      </select>
    </div>
      </div>
```

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :products
  has_many :articles, through: :article_categories
  validates :name , presence: true , length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 25}
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

end
```

[Here is the image of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsXDs.png)

EveryThis is working fine on console but I don't know how to take it from Html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a name to the select tag such as category, then in controller you can access the value with params[:category], but before that you must set values for options in select tag, so you can change select with:

```
<%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(Category.pluck(:name, :id)), class: 'form-control', id: 'sel1' %>
```

```
options_for_select(Category.pluck(:name, :id))
```

will generate the following html

```
<option value="1">Furniture</option>
<option value="2">Animals</option>
<option value="3">Electronics</option>
<option value="4">Computers</option>
```

Note that values depend on your data.

Comment: I am really Thankful to you Taoufik, This is the exact Answer Which I want

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing that how can I show these categories to my product index page if I  use their .  @product.category.name . this is not working or if I try do each method and call by index like product.category.name also not working I'm a newby need your help

Comment: you assign category_id with params[:category] in product's create action ??

Comment: def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:productname, :productprice, :productstatus,:image ,:category )
    end       I did This But not working

Comment: @product = Product.new(product_params) i pass this in my create action

Comment: rename select tag in view with product[category_id]
change product_params to params.require(:product).permit(:productname, :productprice, :productstatus,:image ,:category_id), and in create action Product.create(product_params)

[this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) is a helpful resource to get started with rails

Comment: yes i already try this but not working I post this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63235788/how-to-call-select-tag-in-create-action-in-a-model