# Not able to get pick with select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-6

Actually im getting my category model values from category to take input.....
category_id act as a foreign key in Product Model
I am taking input like this

```
<%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(Category.pluck(:name, :id)), class: 'form-control', id: 'sel1' %>
```

And Pass Category Id in Product_controller Create action like this

```
def create
@product = Product.new(product_params)
@product.user = current_user

  private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:productname, :productprice, :productstatus,:image ,:category )
end
```

But when I create My product An error occurs that category Should be Present.
I think that params[:category] not pass the category_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller code could be like following:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.user = current_user
  @product.save
end

private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:productname, :productprice, :productstatus, :image, :category_id)
end
```

View code will be as following:
Ideally your `category_id` should come in `params[:product]`
Your params should look like `{product: {category_id: 1, other_attr: 'abc'}}`

You must be using `form_for` or `form_with` so use your formbuilder object.

```
<%= form_with(model: @product) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, class: 'form-control', id: 'sel1' %>
<% end %>
```

I have used collection_select you can even use other select helpers.

Another workaround could be using name attribute as `product[category_id]`

```
<%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(Category.pluck(:name, :id)), name: 'product[category_id]', class: 'form-control', id: 'sel1' %>
```

Comment: Thankyou Anand When i use my form builder object with your given  select helper it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches to solve the issue:

First: with actual configuration

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.user = current_user
  @product.category_id = params[:category]
  @product.save
end

private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:productname, :productprice, :productstatus, :image)
end
```

Second: rename select tag to 'product[category_id]'

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.user = current_user
  @product.save
end

private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:productname, :productprice, :productstatus, :image, :category_id)
end
```